# How to change the symbol and colour using fviz_cluster in R project

Tags: r, colors, symbols, pam

I am using R to make the [image: cluster graph].
My code as followed:

```
cluster<- fviz_cluster(final, data = y, labelsize = 1, ellipse.type = "convex", 
              ellipse.alpha = 0 ) 

cluster +   theme(axis.line = element_line(),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         panel.border = element_blank(),
         panel.background = element_blank())
```

And this is my result after deleting all background colors.
So I have a question that, how I can change the symbol of cluster 1 from oval to plus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(factoextra)

data("iris")
head(iris)
# Remove species column (5) and scale the data
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])

# K-means clustering
km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 10)

# Visualize clustering
cluster <- fviz_cluster(km.res, data = iris[, -5], labelsize = 1, 
                        ellipse.type = "convex", 
                        ellipse.alpha = 0) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(3,17,19)) 

cluster + theme(axis.line = element_line(),
                  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                  panel.border = element_blank(),
                  panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]